# Make an element (logo) move according to mouse position

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to replicate the header logo hover thing from this website: https://minhpham.design/

How can I do that in React?

This is what I tried to do:

```
  const [mousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({ x: 0.003, y: 0.003 });
  const [isFirstTime, setIsFirstTime] = useState(true);

  const handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    var xPos: number = e.clientX - 55;
    var yPos: number = e.clientY - 55;

    xPos = Math.min(Math.max(xPos, -15), 15)
    yPos = Math.min(Math.max(yPos, -15), 15)

    setMousePosition({ x: xPos, y: yPos });
  };

  const handleFirstMove = () => {
    setIsFirstTime(false);
  };

  const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setIsFirstTime(true);
    setMousePosition({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  };
```

```
<a
  draggable="false"
  href="/"
  className="h-[5.93vmin] w-[5.93vmin] move-on-hover"
  onMouseEnter={handleFirstMove}
  onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
  onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
  style={{ transform: `translate(${mousePosition.x}%, ${mousePosition.y}%)`, transition: isFirstTime ? "transform 200ms linear" : "none"}}
>
  <img draggable="false" src={icon} alt="icon" />
</a>
```

Comment: you want the logo to move to wherever your mouse pointer is?

Comment: @Kamran Yep, actually I already did that but the problem is that the in and out transition of 200ms works but when hovering inside the div it stays with the transition of 200ms, looking clunky

Comment: Please include your CSS to make an actual [mre].

Answer (score 0):

when onMouseMove you are inside the element I would add it fn handleMouseMove

```
const handleMouseMove = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
  if (isFirstTime) {
    setIsFirstTime(false);
  }
  var xPos: number = e.clientX - 55;
  var yPos: number = e.clientY - 55;

  xPos = Math.min(Math.max(xPos, -15), 15)
  yPos = Math.min(Math.max(yPos, -15), 15)

  setMousePosition({ x: xPos, y: yPos });
};
```